# my button is not created by p5js, and i use addEventListener "click" event with the loop() inside, but the loop once run once when i click that button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, p5.js

```
document.querySelector('#btnStart')
  .addEventListener('click',function(){
         loop();
  });
```

//this is the code, and btnStart is the class selsctor of my button

Comment: Why would `loop()` run more than once? Also, if `btnStart` is the class selector, you're using the wrong syntax in `querySelector`; it should be `'.btnStart'`, not `'#btnStart'`. The latter is for id selectors.

Comment: Did you happen to set noLoop() in your draw() function?

Comment: no, i need to click the button and the loop will run once

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run more than once, you need to actually implement a loop like so:

```
document.querySelector('.btnStart')
  .addEventListener('click',function(){
   let numofLoops = 2 // choose whatever number you want
     for(let i = 0; i < numofLoops; i++){
        loop();
     }
  });
```

Comment: thx for your answer, because in p5js, it said that when i call the loop function, the draw will run continuously

Comment: Unfortunately, i did this without knowing what your ````loop()```` looks like.  Can you copy that code into your comment?

Comment: @wing1224 Please edit your question to include what `loop()` is, and any additional details that are not present in the question.

Comment: by default, my loop() function is the p5.js loops that make draw() loop continuously,

Comment: [loop](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) is the p5.js function.

Comment: i figured out the problem finally, once i click the button, it also trigger the mouseClicked function i set in the js, i don't know why this will happen, because i thought the mouseClicked function will only being called when the mouse is clicked within the canvas, anyway, thx all of your help!